# Can we call consumption of one time purchase from backend rather than billing library?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

One time purchase are consumed using `consumeAsync()` method of Play Billing Library. Is there a way this can be called from backend server or the app has to call it every time ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do it from backend. Consumable purchases are exactly for local usage, so user (app) need to consume them.

Comment: @eleven So the idea was to have verification on backend and then call consume also on backend. But I couldn't find consume api for backend. Only acknowledge api is there